# How to get jdbc connection from hibernate session?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I want to get jdbc connection from hibernate session.There is  method inside hibernate session
i.e session.connection(); but it has been deprecated. i know this works still but i dont want to use deprecated method as i am sure they must have provide some alternative for this?
At http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html connection method api says using org.hibernate.jdbc.Work for this purpose but i dont find any example for that?

Comment: If anyone marks a question as a duplicate please include a link to one of the other questions that already has an answer,

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here is how you can use it:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        //connection, finally!
    }
});
```

Comment: Question: I get `doWork is not valid without active transaction` with this code, how to I start a transaction?

Comment: @OscarRyz: if you are using Spring, `@Transactional` or `TransactionTemplate` is enough. In raw Hibernate you must [run `session.beginTransaction()` manually](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics).

Comment: Hi Buddy.. Nice answer but doWork() is also deprecated now.

Comment: @Logicalj: can you provide some reference? It's [still valid in 4.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work))...

Comment: also worth to mention, there is a doReturningWork(...) method if you want to return a result.

Comment: @Chris, really worth, I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: In Java 8 you can do ```session.doWork(connection -> yourMethodInsideDoWork(connection))``` or even ```session.doWork(this::yourMethodInsideDoWork)```

Comment: Hi everyone.
This video has more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCcfZ4QQAiM

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
((SessionImpl)getSession()).connection()
```

Comment: To anyone who gets here unwarned (just like me): the [`Session.connection`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#connection%28%29) method is currently deprecated.

Comment: never cast to an Impl! its internal! (org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl). And you cannot test this code with a mock anymore. This is bad for many reasons.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar Problem and I used the `ConnectionProvider` class to get the connection. See my solution:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementation = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = sessionFactoryImplementation.getConnectionProvider();
try {
       connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
       ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of how this solves the problem?

Comment: sessionFactoryImplementation.getConnectionProvider() is depricated

Comment: I cannot see that method in Hibernate 5.2.9