# How to make the amazing Hibernate framework provide a connection object from its session?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, hibernate3

Hibernate has deprecated the connection() because they think the framework is so awesome that no-one will ever need the connection. And no, [this is NOT the same thing as providing the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482731/how-to-get-jdbc-connection-from-hibernate-session), unless you are coming from Haskell. Anyways, I have a better idea to get rid of hibernate: a Connection wrapper arounds the hibernate session so I can pass the session around as a connection. I heard there is a way to get the connection with reflection. Does anyone know where I can get a wrapper like that?

```
public class SessionConnection implements Connection {

   private final Session session;
   private final Connection conn;

   public SessionConnection(Session session) {
       this.session = session;
       this.conn = getConnectionFromStupidHibernate(session);
   }

   // delegate methods go here
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but please tell me if you find out as I have been always wanted to do this.

Comment: Hmm...I agree that this is a bit of a pain, but why wouldn't the doWork() solution work for you (no pun intended) ?

Comment: Java is not a functional language. I want to pass the object around so clients can do whatever they want with it. To pass a function or closure around is another thing very different.

Comment: Hibernate team didn't have to think their framework is so awesome to make this change. They might also think there's a finite area that they want to cover. Exposing the raw connection means for them dealing with innumerable angry posts complaining about yet another "bug" in Hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate is like learning Spanish on top of English so you can speak English better. It is a solution to a problem that creates a big problem than the original one. Other than that it is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using spring, just use the same DataSource you use for your SessionFactory - don't design your app around hibernate, fit hibernate into your design

Comment: of course, this has nothing to do with Spring - but usually Spring encourages you to build together a system out of independent objects , rather than just stringing together everything in code in the first way that jumps to mind. anyway setting up hib/spring already has a bean of type DataSource defined somewhere. So all you gotta do is autowire it where you need it

Answer (score 0):

You need a [SessionFactory](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/245.html) and a ConnectionProvider -- see  [Hibernate: Providing Connections](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18406.html).