# using MySQL event scheduler with Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create events using Java code with hibernate. I verified my syntax for CREATE EVENT in MySQL Workbench, and I verified my Java code with a simple UPDATE query. But when I am trying to use both it just doesn't work. I am not getting any error message, just that 0 rows were affected. My code is as follows:

```
String sql = "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS test_event ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 20 SECOND ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE my_table SET last_error_message='my test' WHERE ID=17;";

session.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
....
session.close();
```

thanks a lot

Comment: How you are checking that event is created or not in mysql? I tested, code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know if any new events were created? You can try

```
show events from <SCHEME_NAME>;
```

This will show all the events that are registered to the given schema.try printing the session\statement warning stack...

Answer (score 0):

1. Get jdbc connection from your session: [How to get jdbc connection from hibernate session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482731/how-to-get-jdbc-connection-from-hibernate-session)
2. Use JDBC to execute DDL

...

```
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // ...
} finally {
    // close stmt
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure your database is prepared to execute an event. for that, you need to run the following command.

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

MySQL uses a special thread called event schedule thread to execute all scheduled events.
[image]

if you see your process list like the above picture. you need to run the below command to enable MySQL event execution.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then when you execute the "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" command you will see the below list which shows the specific thread for event execution in MySQL.
[image]

Now you can create your event using any MySQL client interface.